# comparing two strings and reading in a number

Tags: java, string, equals

I have the user to input a string(command).
and my code is to check what the user have inputted.
such as "ADD" "DIVIDE" "SUBTRACT" etc...

and there will be a number attached along with it like this.
"ADD3" or "ADD5"

how should I code this in a efficient way,
instead of doing crazy amount of if statements

this is what I have right now

```
public class Cell {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    String command = "";

    command= JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter The Command" );

    if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("ADD")) {
              BLAH BLAH BLAH
}
```

Comment: look if user enters `ADD 3` it would be more easy to fetch the number.

Comment: Please provide complete code applicable for above use-case.

Comment: Java 7 allows `switch` with `Strings`. Or you can use a `Map` where the keys are 'ADD', 'SUB, 'DIV', ...

Comment: You have too litte right now...

Comment: You could use reflection to "switch" on the method name. ;)

Comment: You could have something like this:  `add 3 5` or `multiply 5 6` or combine as you wish: `add 3 5 multiply 10` or think of a better way to represent commands.
`add3` `add5` doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: @LewsTherin I think he means "add 3 to the current amount" (but I'm not sure, this question is quite ambiguous)

Comment: @Doorknob Even so, that's a lot of effort. I *hate* effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should do:

```
userInput.toLowerCase().startsWith("add"); // or divide/subtract/multiply...
```

I think this code is pretty self explanatory, except for the `toLowerCase()` perhaps. That's to simulate case insensitivity.

Comment: @Oxtis Just make sure none of the operations is a prefix of another, or this may not work. (Or you can sort them by length to avoid this problem.)

Answer (score 2):

The most efficient way is following
suppose user input `ADD 3`

```
String[] inputs=command.split(" ");
String actualCommand=inputs[0];
int number=Integer.parseInt(inputs[1])
```

after this use a `switch` or `if-else` to check the actual command and do stuff with number.

Comment: Most Java versions don't allow switch statements with Strings.

Comment: so you can use normal `if-else` statements. :)

Comment: Yes, I commented just so readers with < Java 7 wouldn't come back and downvote your answer because it didn't work.